# Can't install Tensorflow, receiving both numpy and a TypeError: unsupported callable errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow

I recently tried to install Tensorflow, following the instructions in their tutorial. While the installation itself worked fine, when I tried to import it, I got this:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 977, in getfullargspec
   skip_bound_arg=False)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 1957, in _signature_internal
   skip_bound_arg=skip_bound_arg)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 1890, in _signature_from_builtin
  raise ValueError("no signature found for builtin {!r}".format(func))
ValueError: no signature found for builtin <method 'max' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
 from tensorflow.python import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
  import tensorflow.contrib as contrib
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
  from tensorflow.contrib import learn
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
  from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
 from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn import *
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
  from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.io import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
  from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.io.dask_io import *
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/io/dask_io.py", line 23, in <module>
  import dask.dataframe as dd
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
 from .core import (DataFrame, Series, Index, _Frame, map_partitions,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 1252, in <module>
  class Index(Series):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py", line 1284, in Index
  @derived_from(pd.Index)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dask/utils.py", line 530, in wrapper
  original_args = getargspec(original_method).args
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dask/compatibility.py", line 222, in getargspec
  return _getargspec(func)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/dask/compatibility.py", line 44, in _getargspec
  return inspect.getfullargspec(func)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/inspect.py", line 983, in getfullargspec
  raise TypeError('unsupported callable') from ex
TypeError: unsupported callable
```

And after uninstalling it, updating Protobuf and pip, and re-installing multiple times, I still get this same error. What could be the problem?

Comment: What version of Pandas have you installed?

Comment: Pip3 show gives this: `Metadata-Version: 1.1 Name: pandas Version: 0.13.1`

Comment: Well, that is exactly the problem. You must upgrade `pandas` to a more recent version (Preferably `0.18.1`) if you intend on using `dask`. Or you could remove dask completely from the packages installed by `tensorflow`. That version of yours is pretty outdated as of now.

Comment: @nickil-maveli I just tried to upgrade pandas and it gave me an error: `error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1`